# Бэкапы без остановки ВМ на KVM

Tags: linux, kvm

Необходимо делать бэкапы ВМ (linux и Windows) на гипервизоре KVM. Простых и стабильных решений того, как это делать, к сожалению, не нашел. Поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста, как это лучше делать, общие рекомендации, чтобы избежать неприятностей в будующем. Если нужна какая-то доп инфа, задавайте вопросы.
Рекомендации типа ставь vmware,xen и пр., пожалуйста, не предлагайте.
Использую
KVM + CentOS7.2

Comment: Технологию Checkpointing-Restore (CRIU) пробовали?

Comment: Нет , не пробовал. В вики написано, что эта утилита делает контрольную точку программы, что не совсем то, что мне нужно. Поправьте , если не прав

Comment: Хорошо, до дефиса вы осилили перевод, теперь осталась часть после. В общем, читайте дальше -- вы на правильном пути!

Comment: Понял, буду смотреть что за оно

Comment: Вот вам ещё ключевых слов для поиска: Container live migration.

Answer (score 0):

Если виртуальный диск на lvm, то я делаю снапшот с диска. Монтирую со смещением и извлекаю данные.

Способы есть разные для разных данных. Можно просто снапшот снимать и хранить как есть.

Comment: Я тоже так думал делать, но было много информации о том, что просто  необходимо машину все таки фризить на время создания снапшота. Возможно я не прав, но именно из-за этого я даже не стал пробовать, опять же, возможно зря.